# Primefaces Push - TimeoutException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, websocket, push, primefaces-push

I'm using the primefaces push framework in my application. It usually works fine and the sockets are sending the data without a problem. However sometimes it looks like my request is not being processed and after about 30 seconds the following exception is written to my log file.

```
2016-02-15T15:50:26.323+0100|Warnung: StandardWrapperValve[Push Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Push Servlet threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:375)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:700)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:970)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:270)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:283)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:325)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:177)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:203)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:279)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.readEntirelyAsString(IOUtils.java:155)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.readEntirely(IOUtils.java:106)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy.onRequest(PushEndpointHandlerProxy.java:151)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:223)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:115)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:71)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2285)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:191)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:177)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:127)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    ... 63 more
```

After said exception the application is not working correctly anymore and the sockets receive constant java script errors. The following exception is then constantly being written to the log.

```
2016-02-15T15:50:26.342+0100|Warnung: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@52e4cd39: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable, location=/errors/500.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:834)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextWrapper.java:785)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextWrapper.java:785)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:390)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    ... 29 more
----- Root Cause -----
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getWriter(Response.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getWriter(ResponseFacade.java:224)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getWriter(ServletResponseWrapper.java:152)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextImpl.java:834)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextWrapper.java:785)
    at javax.faces.context.ExternalContextWrapper.getResponseOutputWriter(ExternalContextWrapper.java:785)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.createResponseWriter(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:1169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:390)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.application.PrettyViewHandler.renderView(PrettyViewHandler.java:163)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:492)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:246)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My web.xml looks as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>iPCC</display-name>
    <module-name>iPCC</module-name>

    <!-- WEB SERVICE -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>WSServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>ipcc</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/call</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/device/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/facility/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/axiome/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/monitor</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/event</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/callQueuing</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>SystemUserRole</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>ipcc</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginerror</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <!-- JSF mapping -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- PUSH -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- MIME mapping -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>gif</extension>
        <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>png</extension>
        <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/timeOutPage.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.ilogs.ipcc.common.exception.AxiomeDeviceNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/axiomeDeviceNotFound.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/errors/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/errors/500.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/errors/404.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>401</error-code>
        <location>/errors/401.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>403</error-code>
        <location>/errors/403.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
    <context-param>
        <description>iPCC svn revision</description>
        <param-name>svn.revision</param-name>
        <param-value>@@svn.revision@@</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <description>iPCC version</description>
        <param-name>version</param-name>
        <param-value>@@version@@</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.BASE_PACKAGES</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ilogs</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.SCAN_LIB_DIRECTORY</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.mobile.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>none</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.FONT_AWESOME</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.UPLOADER</param-name>
        <param-value>commons</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/ipcc.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>1048576</param-value> <!-- 1MB -->
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.writeStateAtFormEnd</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useStream</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Session configuration -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>15</session-timeout>

        <cookie-config>
            <http-only>true</http-only>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>

    <!-- web fonts -->
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>eot</extension>
        <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>otf</extension>
        <mime-type>font/opentype</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>ttf</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>woff2</extension>
        <mime-type>application/x-font-woff2</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>svg</extension>
        <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

    <!-- Filters -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.iLogs.jee.utils.LocaleFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>ERROR</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

---

Primefaces 5.3.4,
Atmosphere 2.4.2,
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.0 (build 89).

Comment: The underlying problem is `getOutputStream() has already been called for this response`. Maybe related:  http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35281